# Can we mount sub-directories of a named volume in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The docker-compose file https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volume-driver shows various ways to mount host sub-directories relative to the compose file.

For example:

```yaml
volumes:
   # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
   - /var/lib/mysql
 
   # Specify an absolute path mapping
   - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql
 
   # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
   - ./cache:/tmp/cache
 
   # User-relative path
   - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro
 
   # Named volume
   - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Is is possible to mount a sub-directory of a named volume at a specific location?  For example something like below, which I tried, but does not seem to work.

```
# Named volume
  - datavolume/sql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I am assuming I might be able to manage this by mounting the data volume to a location like `/data` and then in the Dockerfiles for each container, create symbolic links from the sub-directories to the locations.

for example in a docker-compose.yml file

```
volumes:
  - datavolume:/data
```

and then in the container Dockerfile

```
RUN ln -s /data/sql_data /var/lib/mysql
```

I started going down this path but it was getting messy and was not working.  Before I either abandon that approach or invest the time debugging it, I wanted to make sure there was no way to just specify sub-directories of a named vollume.

Comment: couldn't you mount it somewhere like datavolume:/var/datavolume and in the container do `ln -s /var/datavolume/dql_data /var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167198/6309) to include a workaround.

Comment: Q1 2024: [`docker mount` can mount a subfolder of a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167198/6309).

Comment: March 2024, with [moby v26.0.0](https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v26.0.0), this is now supported.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

2023: As noted by [Michael Bolli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710921/michael-bolli) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164939/can-we-mount-sub-directories-of-a-named-volume-in-docker/38167198?noredirect=1#comment135175397_38167198), that feature is now a work-in-progress:

[PR 45687: "volumes: Implement subpath mount"](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/45687)

> Make it possible to mount subdirectory of a named volume.

Q1 2024: this is merged! [Commit 31ccdbb](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/31ccdbb7a80c248d06d248e60d6566adb4ec5023).
Possibly for Moby 26.0.

March 2024, as mentioned in [issue 32582](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582#issuecomment-1988310212):

> > CLI already supports it (starting from v26.0.0-rc1): [`docker/cli` PR #4331](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/4331)
>
> (and you can already install it from the `test` channel)
>
> Compose support is still WIP (it needs to move to v26 first).

March 2024: [Paweł Gronowski](https://github.com/vvoland) confirms in [the same issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582#issuecomment-2012362454):

> [moby v26.0.0](https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v26.0.0) is released, so you can already try out this feature.

---

2016: No because [`compose/config/config.py#load(config_details)`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/59e96fea4f6c33dc8d49ef970bb2463f0288efda/compose/config/config.py#L321-L323) check if `datavolume/sql_data` matches a named volume (in [`compose/config/validation.py#match_named_volumes()`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/ac82597ac10c9a0dbd3bf25ebde792e9cc71efc4/compose/config/validation.py#L66-L75)).

`datavolume` would, `datavolume/sql_data` would not.

As [memetech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702842/memetech) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164939/can-we-mount-sub-directories-of-a-named-volume-in-docker/38167198#comment89745114_38167198), the is an issue tracking this since April 2017:
[`moby/moby` issue 32582](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582): "**[feature] Allow mounting sub-directories of named volumes**".

In that issue, [Joohansson](https://github.com/Joohansson) adds ([see comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582#issuecomment-643126372))

> In the meantime, I use this workaround to mount the whole volume on a separate path and then symlink it to the sub path.
>
> ```
> # In the Dockerfile:
> RUN mkdir -p /data/subdir
> RUN ln -s /data/subdir /var/www/subdir
> ```
>
> Then mount the volume as normal.
> The `/subdir` must exist in the volume.
>
> ```
> docker run -d -v myvol:/data mycontainer
> ```
>
> Now anything read or written by the webserver will be stored in the volume `subdir` and can't access the other data.

Comment: This feature would be awesome. Also looking for same functionality instead of polluting more named volumes.

Comment: Feature is open as of 2018-07-17 https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582

Comment: Feature is now a work-in-progress: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582#issuecomment-1593512466 -> https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/45687

Comment: @MichaelBolli Thank you for your feedback. I will include your comment in the answer [as soon as I am able to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425430/6309).

Comment: @MichaelBolli Done. I have edited the answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
You can just create normal sub directories into the volume and then in your application link or configure to use that path.

Let's say you use this compose volume definition :

```
    volumes:
      - myVolume:/mnt/data
volumes:
  myVolume:
```

The volume setup is irrelevant, but only the mounpoint matters, assuing the mount point inside container is "/mnt/data/"

Then in you application just point to sub directories:
logging to /mnt/data/log,
database files to /mnt/data/db
configs to /mnt/config

For example doing this in DockeFile

```
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/data/log
RUN mkdir /mnt/data/db
RUN mkdir /mnt/data/config
RUN sed ... to change logging path to /mnt/data/log
RUN mv /current/db/data/files /mnt/data/db
RUN ln /mnt/data/db /current/db/data/files 
...
```