# How to share sub folders from a docker named volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is a sample symfony project:

```
my_project:
    assets:
    src:
    web:
    package.json
    composer.json
```

I have an **apache** container and a container with **webpack** that will be used to watch the *assets* folder and build it when something changes.

As both containers need access to the same filesystem, let's say I:

- Create a named volume
- Copy my_project in it using this [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468788/what-is-the-right-way-to-add-data-to-an-existing-named-volume-in-docker)
- Run some `composer install` and `npm install` commands

Once everything is ready, I need the **apache** container to share the *src* folder with the host and the **webpack** container to share the *assets* folder with the host.
That way, everytime I change a file in those folders, I would be able to see the result in my browser.

I saw that it's not [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164939/can-we-mount-sub-directories-of-a-named-volume-in-docker) for the moment to mount subdirectories so what other way is there?
Or am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Since mounting subdirectories of named volumes is [not a possibility](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582), maybe you can try the following.

As I see it, multiple containers need access to the same filesystem. According to the docker [volume docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume):

> Remember that multiple containers can mount the same volume, and it can be mounted read-write for some of them and read-only for others, at the same time.

So essentially, you can create a single docker volume and share it between all your containers:

```
# Initialize the Docker Volume
docker volume create my_project_volume
docker run -v my_project_volume:/my_project --name helper alpine true
docker cp . helper:/my_project
docker rm helper
```

If you want your applications (such as apache) to only access subfolders within your volume, you can always mount the volume to `/` (or anywhere of your choosing), and create a symlink from the directory your application will access to the volume subdirectory. For example:

```
# 1. Run your apache container, mounting the named volume to root dir
docker run -v my_project_volume:/my_project --name my_apache httpd:latest

# 2. Create symlink to named volume subdirectory
docker exec -it my_apache ln -s /usr/local/apache2/htdocs /my_project/src
```