# Docker volume replace previous volume

Tags: docker

I have docker-compose file, where I have specified volumes:

```
    services:

        portal:
            env_file:
            - ${ENV_FILE}
            build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
            container_name: sensus-portal
            image: sensus-portal
            hostname: ${DOMAIN}
            working_dir: /var/www/html
            volumes:
            - ../localhost-certificates:/var/certificates
            - ./portal:/var/www/html
            - ../wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
            ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
```

Problem is that when last volume added, it replaces previous stuffs which was in `var/www/html/wp-content` ... I want to assign volume `/var/www/html` and then into this add (merge) volume `/var/www/html/wp-content.`

Is there any chance how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we mount sub-directories of a named volume in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164939/can-we-mount-sub-directories-of-a-named-volume-in-docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there’s no way to merge the contents of two volumes or host directories.  This works the same way as normal Linux **mount**(8): the directory or volume you’re mounting into the container hides whatever was there already, and there’s no way to get at the hidden content.

The Dockerfile COPY directive is a little more flexible this way and you might consider building this content into your image.