# Is it possible to specify a folder path from a docker compose volume?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, haproxy

I have a some docker containers that I host on Windows Azure. I also have storage that I use for persistent data. Inside the storage I created this folder structure : **acishare/haproxy/enduser** and **acishare/haproxy/promoter**.

In the code below, I want to mount **acishare/haproxy/enduser** as a volume inside the docker compose configuration:

```
loadbalancer:
    image: haproxytech/haproxy-ubuntu:2.5
    ...
    volumes:
      - haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy

volumes:
  haproxy:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: acishare
      storage_account_name: tctstorage2
      storage_account_key: <account_key>
```

This code allows to fetch the **acishare** folder only. However, I need to mount **acishare/haproxy/enduser**. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This currently is not possible with Docker, though it has been requested as a feature for quite some time now:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582

As [SidShetye commented on the Github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582#issuecomment-613684067), as of 15 April 2020 it was:

> the 2nd oldest issue (2/3500)
>
> the 8th most commented issue (8/3500)
>
> the 7th most thumbs-up'd issue (7/3500)

If this functionality is something you critically need, then you may want to look to Kubernetes, as they support [subpaths for volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-lamp-site
spec:
    containers:
    - name: mysql
      image: mysql
      env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: "rootpasswd"
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        name: site-data
        subPath: mysql
    - name: php
      image: php:7.0-apache
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html
        name: site-data
        subPath: html
    volumes:
    - name: site-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-lamp-site-data
```

Comment: March 2024: this is [now supported!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167198/6309) with Moby v26.0.0+.